# How i can create different menu for each WooCommerce Product Category?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming, hook-woocommerce

Please help me with a tip about Wordpress,

I have **9 menus** created and **9 WooCommerce Category** created too but I don't know how i call each menu in respective WooCommerce Product Category.

[image: Wordpress > Products > Categorie]

I use the theme AVADA from Themeforest, but my theme leave me just set up one menu for all WooCommerce Category:

[image: AVADA theme option]

But I must use a different menu for each WooCommerce Product Category.

[image: MENU-category-01]

Answer (score 2):

This is the solution I found it can help you:

You have to override the archive product template from your woocommerce plugin folder by copying `archive-product.php` to `yourtheme/woocommerce/archive-product.php`. Edit the file, and add this code at the beginning (or wherever the menu needs to show up):

```
<?php 

if ( is_tax( 'product_cat', 'category1' )) {
    wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'menu1' ) ); 
}

elseif ( is_tax( 'product_cat', 'category2' )) {
    wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'menu2' ) ); 
}

else ( is_tax( 'product_cat', 'category3' )) {
    wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'menu3' ) ); 
}

?>
```

menu1 will be displayed when we're on the products page that belongs to category category1.

menu2 will be displayed when we're on the products page that belongs to category category2.